# MvxTabbedPage has a too large header

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin Forms app and use MvvmCross. My MainPage uses a MvxTabbedPage with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:MvxTabbedPage x:TypeArguments="viewModels:MainViewModel" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MoneyFox.Views"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
            xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MoneyFox.Business.ViewModels;assembly=MoneyFox.Business"
            x:Class="MoneyFox.Views.MainPage">
    <views:MvxTabbedPage.Children>
        <pages:AccountListPage Title="Fooo1" />
        <pages:AccountListPage Title="Fooo2" />
        <pages:AccountListPage Title="Fooo3" />
    </views:MvxTabbedPage.Children>
</views:MvxTabbedPage>
```

This works so far. But the header is quite big:

[image]

In contrast the one from the Xamarin Forms Templates in VS:

[image]

It seems there is an additional bar in between. My Tabbar and Toolbar Resource is analog to the default. I also tried to remove them, without success. Did I miss an Option or something here?

Answer (score 0):

I found an example in the MvvmCross PlayGround:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/Projects/Playground/Playground.Forms.UI/Pages/TabsRootPage.xaml.cs

With the right attributes and adding the pages through the navigation it worked.